# Как заблокировать выход с веб-страницы на Android-устройстве?

Tags: android, webbrowser

Есть интерактивный стенд на Android 4.4. На нем будет запущен определенный сайт в виде веб-приложения. Как пользователям запретить выходить с этого сайта и вообще закрывать браузер (как будто активирован полноэкранный режим). Чтобы пользователи могли пользоваться интерактивным стендом только в пределах данной веб-страницы. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делал приложение с подобным функционалом. У вас стенд с кнопками системными (назад, домой и еще одна) на экране или с аппаратными?

Я использовал планшеты с кнопками на экране и просто при запуске активити делал так:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
```

Так же добавил это, чтобы экран не гас, даже если в настройках системы стоит таймер на отключение дисплея:

```
//keep screen on
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Плюс, для того чтобы при открытии клавы ничего обратно не вылезло:

В манифесте для активити добавил:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

и в коде:

```
findViewById(android.R.id.content).setSystemUiVisibility(8);
```

Если же кнопки аппаратные, то надо еще добавить обработчик этих кнопок, чтобы при нажатии ничего не происходило:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //ничего не делаем
}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENVELOPE:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_MUTE:
            Log.d("Ignoring buttons");
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы будете открывать сайт в своем приложении через WebView или в обычном браузере?

Если у вас свое приложение, то вызовите `startLockTask()` у активности, включится режим киоска и покинуть приложение будет нельзя, до тех пор пока режим не отключится, для отключения режима нужно зажать комбинацию клавиш на устройстве

Подробнее можно почитать [тут](http://www.azoft.ru/blog/android-kiosk-mode/)

Если Вы будете использовать стандартный браузер, то не знаю как это сделать

Comment: Не обратил внимания, что стенд на 4.4

startLockTask 5.0+